# How do I scroll to an item using the mouse wheel on Angular

Tags: angularjs

I've got some trouble.
I've got home page with 4 div elements with a different id.
Example:

```html
<div id='one' class='sectionscroll'></div>
<div id='two' class='sectionscroll'></div>
<div id='three' class='sectionscroll'></div>
<div id='four' class='sectionscroll'></div>
```

All these div elements pick the height from the screen.
When page loads I made an automatic scroll to the div with id two `<div id='two'></div>`.

And from this position, I want to scroll to another position.
But I couldn't understand how to make this.

This is my factory which made slow scroll to position by using ng-click.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.scroll.home.page', [])
        .factory('$scrollHomePage', $scrollHomePage);

    $scrollHomePage.inject = [];

    function $scrollHomePage() {
        return {
            scrollTo: function(eId) {

                var startY = currentYPosition();
                var stopY = elmYPosition(eId);
                var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
                if (distance < 100) {
                    scrollTo(0, stopY);
                    return;
                }
                var speed = Math.round(distance / 65);
                if (speed >= 250) speed = 250;
                var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
                var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
                var timer = 0;
                if (stopY > startY) {
                    for (var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
                        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
                        leapY += step;
                        if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY;
                        timer++;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                for (var i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, " + leapY + ")", timer * speed);
                    leapY -= step;
                    if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY;
                    timer++;
                }

                function currentYPosition() {
                    if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
                        history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
                    }
                    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                        return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                    return 0;
                }

                function elmYPosition(eID) {
                    var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                    var y = elm.offsetTop;
                    var node = elm;
                    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                        node = node.offsetParent;
                        y += node.offsetTop;
                    }
                    return y;
                }
            }

        };
    }
})();
```

and in controller I used automatical scroll by

```
$(window).load(function () {
            $("div.sectionscroll").height($('body').height());
            $location.hash('');
            $scrollHomePage.scrollTo('two');
        });
```

Comment: lets see what youve tried, what are you doing onload that scrolls div "two" into view?

Comment: I make service witch make scrollTo my position. $(window).load(function () {
            $("div").height($('body').height());
            $location.hash('');
            $scrollHomePage.scrollTo('two');
        });

Comment: I think this I must made by using preventDefault(); But I don't understand how make it perfect.

Comment: I update my question plz look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got my answer done. May be some one need this. So enjoy it. :)

```
 var currentPosition = 1;
            angular.element(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", debounce(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                var isUp = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? true : false;

                if (isUp) {
                    if (currentPosition > 0) {
                        currentPosition--;
                        setPoinerActive();
                        $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (currentPosition < 3) {
                        currentPosition++;
                        setPoinerActive();
                        $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]); return;
                    }
                }
            },300));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Volodymyr If I got your question correctly, you need to scroll to a particular hash (`id of div`)
You can use `$anchorScroll` and `$location` services of angular.

Below code will scroll to a div with id `output` and you can even add an offset to the scroll position if you want to take the user to a bit lower position than the exact div

```
$anchorScroll.yOffset = 30; // to add extra top margin
$location.hash('output');
$anchorScroll();
```

You can then call this function on `ng-click` of a button or something you want.

Comment: Thank you for answer but $anchorScroll is a good for using,$anchorScroll haven't got animation effects . But I need it slowely, like you use mouseweel. And I make my factory wich made this scroll if I use ng-click. But my problem is make something like ng-click event, but using mouseweel and go to another position tha same.